# Intellij is acting weird returning everything

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij 14 and I'm encountering something really really strange while debugging and check breakpoints, for example having the below code:

```
public SQLiteDatabase getDB()
    {
        try {
            return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, 0);
        }
        catch(SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Log.e("DATABASE",
                    "Failed to open database",
                    ex);
        }
        finally {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Afaik if there is no problem in the try scope then it will return, but in my case it just passes the try scope normally and then it goes right into the finally scope. This is one scenario, the other one I've faced once before, here's the 2nd scenario:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(String str)
{
    if(str != null && str.trim().length() > 0 && !str.equals(""))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and I make sure the str is not empty or null or anything, but then again while debugging it goes into the scope and run the **return false;** but then it goes to **return true;** right after.... it's driving me crazy because while I'm not debugging using breakpoints it doesn't work, but running the project normally it works.

I can't figure it out why is it like this... it's driving me crazy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `invalidate caches` and restart IDEA.

Comment: And for the first code snippet: do not return anything in the `finally` block - because this block is being executed no matter what happens - and i'm not sure what the outcome would be.

Comment: @fateddy what do you mean it will be executed? even though I'm returning the database in try scope? then it will return null afterwards? how's will that work ? I'm confused.

Comment: Regarding the `return null` in the finally - this is very odd since you should always return null from this method (since finally always runs). One thought is that the compiler is actually just "optimizing away" the try block since it has no effect (i.e. method always returns null). Shouldnt the null return statement be in the catch, rather than the finally?

Comment: @cjstehno yea you're right, it should be like that and i will change it but still in the second scenario how's that possible to return both first true and then false? any idea?

Comment: @arashmoeen - finally is always executed. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: @cjstehno yea you're right, thanks for the link, but do you have any idea about the 2nd scenario? the 2nd code.

Comment: Are you sure its hitting the `return false` line and not just the end of the method. I have noticed that the IntelliJ debugger will stop on the end of a method - maybe to show exit conditions or something. I don't see anything in the code that would seem to cause an issue. Are you actually getting false as the return value (like from the next step outside the method)?

Comment: @cjstehno yea at first I thought the same but then the boolean result is being used in another function calling this one and it's always false when I'm debugging only though.

Comment: This looks like common case of desynchronizing application being debugged with actual code. I suggest redeploying your application.

Comment: @mareckmareck Thanks for your reply but can you explain more about desynchronizing application? and what do you mean by redeploying my code?

Comment: I meant, that if you changed anything in the code after compiling and running the application, the lines of codes will not match - debugger will run by lines from compile time, while you look at edited code. If that happens you should simply restar the application, though you've probably done that by now.

Comment: @mareckmareck oh well, I know that but I didn't get you at first and I'm pretty sure that's not the case here. I understand that intellij likes to reach the end of the method which happens sometimes to me as well but I don't get it why would it just send the false value as a return value while true should be returned. That function's been there for a while and I didn't change it, not after compile. well intellij is not the perfect issueless ide anyway.